# Is it wrong to rewrite an entire answer of mine, long after it has been accepted, if it's a big improvement?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, accepted-answer

Today I got this comment on a 2 year old answer of mine:

> Can you please fix the english and punctuation errors? What does gray in the corner indicate? Why is its color lighter? What is 4x? Width of the lines in second second shape or total number of pixels in it ? And why didn't you just draw a line rather than intereection of two lines? What about orange rectanles? Although I know the concept very well, your drawings and shallow/complicated/missing writing confused me! Gosh my brain!

It's not the friendliest way to provide feedback. In fact, I more or less stopped after "Can you please fix the english and punctuation errors?" and just skimmed the rest of it. But it got me to re-read my answer and take a look at the illustrations in the original answer (which I felt was lacking but OK to begin with) and decided that I could come up with both a better explanation and better illustrations.

So I decided to rewrite the answer to really put that comment down.

As I was finished I realized that the new answer, while still talking about the same thing, was very different from the old one. So my question is:

**Is it wrong to rewrite an entire answer long after it has been accepted (and up voted)?**

I feel that the new answer is much better and the people who voted for the original answer would surely have voted for this answer as well. But it's not the "same" answer that they actually voted for.

In case you want to look at the answer in question: [this is the rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11176658/5), and [this is the original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11176658/2).

Comment: See, improving answers also wins you badges! (Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11176658/2235132)

Comment: If you are worried about potentially lost effort, have a look at the amount of views. In your case its more than once per day, so I would expect it to help people in the future, so it is worth as much effort as writing it the first day.

Comment: @devnull there's a lot of people couldn't care less about badges...

Comment: It's good to see that [Muphry's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law) still holds, at least.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> Is it wrong to rewrite an entire answer long after it has been accepted (and up voted)?

- Does your rewrite improve your answer?
- Does your rewritten answer still answer the question as it originally did?

If both questions are answered with "yes", there is no problem.

Comment: It's annoying to come back to an answer you upvoted and discover it's been edited to be wrong, and you have to take your vote off. But it's much less annoying and less common, than the problems we'd have if we refrained from improving answers.

Answer (score 11):

Before answering this question, I'd like to point out [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176560/uibezierpath-stroke-1px-line-and-fill-1px-width-rectangle-different-results/11176658#comment35603456_11176658) in response to the point about language and punctuation errors.  I don't see anything wrong in the comments so as to make that remark.  It was unwarranted, IMO.  If it were an offensive/rude comment then you might as well flag it for moderator attention.

That said, it is usual for people to improve their answers long after answering those.  The usual case is that you might not have a certain perspective about the problem at the time of answering but later realize that the post could be improved.

If the post in question has a high number of visits, it makes all the more reason to improve an existing answer.

Comment: While not immediately rude or offensive, I have to agree with David that I don't particularly like the tone of the comments.

Comment: @Bart Perhaps I've seen quite a number of such comments that it feels rather mild in comparison :)

Comment: @Bart And quite a few of those happen to be from those lacking _minimal understanding_, that it find it better to ignore.

Comment: “Although I know the concept very well, your drawings and shallow/complicated/missing writing confused me!” is pretty rude

Comment: I think the rudeness of it really depends on your cultural background.  The commenter may just be used to rather direct statements.  It's probably better to maintain a more graceful tone, in the interest of soliciting a better response, but I didn't find the comment particularly offensive.

Comment: I can see why it would raise your hackles, but it looks like you may both be non-native English speakers.  It can be hard to maintain the tone you're looking for in a second (or higher) language.  I try to give a little extra leeway in those cases.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it depends on the situation:

- If the new answer is **significantly different** from the old one, post it as a **new** answer.
- If the changes you make are **comparatively minor**, just amend the **old** answer.

The up/down-votes and comments attached to the old answer were given in response to what it said originally, so making significant alterations after the fact might make things confusing. Also, just because someone up-voted the *old* answer doesn't mean that they will agree with your new one, even if *you* think that it's "better".

Comment: Unfortunately, if you post it as a new answer, most people won't even read it, because it will go to the bottom of this topic (which by now is quite old according to the OP). Most people won't scroll down and look at old answers with zero votes if the question is quite old - they'll assume that the accepted/most-voted answer contains the collective wisdom of the responders. Nevertheless your answer is well-written and thought-provoking so I haven't downvoted it.